# Why are some outlets in my bedroom working and some do not/

Tags: electrical

I have 5 outlets in bedroom 3 stopped working. tripped circuit breaker nothing. Why would this happen?

Comment: Have you checked for any GFCI outlets in the area that might control those outlets?

Comment: Are all these outlets on the same circuit?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: When you say "tripped circuit breaker nothing" what does that mean?  Does that mean it did NOT trip the circuit breaker, or it did trip the breaker and now will not power up?  *What were you doing **right before** the circuit breaker tripped?*  The more you tell us, the more we can help, so fess up ;)

Comment: Are some of the outlets...'switched'?  So you can turn on a table lamp from a wall switch (and sometimes only half an outlet is switch controlled).

Answer (score 1):

Hard saying without more info.  However, assuming all 5 outlets are on the same circuit I would say what happened is all of your outlets are daisy chained together.  The two that are working are earlier on in the chain.  The next outlet in the chain something went wrong with it, thus affecting all the outlets after it.